# How should I act after landing in big airport

Tags: landing, airport, ppl

So I have a PPL, in the time of my education I did some touch and goes in international airports, but never parked there.
I am planning now to fly to Dresden Airport from Prague, and I am a bit confused about how should I act after landing and arriving to the GA apron.

Is there anywhere I can read what to do?
How should I leave the airplane? Just take the keys?
How to exit the airport? How to come back? Should I do a security check when going back to the airplane?

Comment: Does Dresden require GA visitors to use a handling agent?

Comment: I don't know, how should I check it? Checked in jeppesen charts, didn't find something about handling agent

Comment: Personally I would act poor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to follow all the local regulations from the aviation authority in the country in question. I can tell you what typical where I fly but this may vary. Most of the information for [Dresden is listed here](https://www.mdf-ag.com/en/b2b/aviation-and-handling/general-aviation/dresden-airport/) but in general:

You will *likely* be met by a marshaler who will show you where to park after you land and get taxi directions to your ramp of choice.

Typically transient GA planes are left locked, with the parking break off so that ground crews can move them about the ramp without you. Ive never left the keys to my plane with a ground crew and wouldn't even if asked. They dont need to get *in* my plane to move it. They will likely instruct you on what to do when you power down. The typical call out in the states is "parking break off?" before the marshaler drives away in his golf cart...

If you cross a border and need to clear customs you need to make sure that the airport in question has customs and then you will need to deal with any arrangements you may need to (including paperwork) before hand to make sure you can actually get cleared.

Most airports where I fly have some kind of an office/fixed base operations/management facility where you can physically exit the field (and [it appears Dresden has a nice lounge](https://www.mdf-ag.com/en/b2b/aviation-and-handling/general-aviation/dresden-airport/)). This is typically where you also pay for fuel and overnight parking. You will return through this facility as well. Again most major airports are open 24/7 (even GA facilities) but you should confirm this with them in advance if you intend on coming and going at odd hours.

You will not need to go through "security" in the typical airport sense to get back to your aircraft since you are using the private terminal. However as noted above you may need to organize some customs related things.

Also of note, if you are flying into a busy city airport they will expect you to be on top of your stuff. You may need to read back long taxi instructions, wait for a while on a taxi way for other flights to leave etc.

---

[Here is a fascinating series of videos on flying into a country that has almost no GA support](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ya4BHlGtvFU&list=PLUpuAnvsj4dNmQRmar7aZ4qWThN6QZ0OH)

Comment: As the Czech Republic and Germany are both Schengen member states, the OP will not need to clear customs. At this time there are also no special COVID-related entry requirements for Germany. There may be other requirements I'm not aware of though.

Comment: Good answer. I happened to land in Dresden a few weeks ago and park overnight. You will be met by a marshaller and guided to a parking position. Tiedown points exist on the tarmac and the marshaller will provide you with chocks and ropes if necessary, then drive you to the general aviation terminal. You just walk through a door into the arrival hall, maybe after telling the clerk's desk which aircraft you are and how long you will stay. On departure, you start with the door and clerk's desk again, pay your bill (expect 50€) and they will call a marshaller to pick you up. (@MeirTolpin)

Answer (score 1):

1. Find out where the German AIS - Aeronautical Information Sevice is (google ais deutchland)
2. In AIS DE locate AIP - Aeronautical Information Publication
3. From AIP find section AD 2 AERODROMES

AD 2 Should have at least some of the information you need or instructions on who/what to contact for more info, also browse through the rest of the AIS for full understanding of operating in German airspace/aerodromes. You can always call the aerodrome and ask, contact info will be listed in AIP.

I'm hoping I've stated the obvious here, because the above is basic knowledge for PPL